# Dim inactive compiz ( set speed of the effect)

Tags: 13.04, compiz, brightness

I just enabled the `dim inactive` effect in `compiz` on ubuntu 13.04 and my question is:

How can I speed up this effect? With this I mean how can I reduce the time it takes to make the background less bright?

Answer (score 1):

I used the `Fading Windows` section in `Compwiz` to adjust the fading speed.

The options there are similar to `gconf-editor` which was suggested by @nicolas. However, for some reason, `gconf-editor` adjustment doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just find the solution to your problem.

This can be updated using gconf-editor from a terminal.
Then navigate to :

/apps/compiz-1/plugins/fade/screen0/options/dim_unresponsive

Here you would be able to change the dimming speed